# Image captured from canvas and uploaded id getting corrupt from middle

Tags: javascript, file-upload, html5-canvas, getusermedia, todataurl

I am using getUserMedia API to capture the camera stream and capture images using canvas from stream's snapshot.

This was working fine for a while, however recently we have been receiving corrupt images as attached in 1 of 50 uploads. 
No specific pattern was established.

[image]

Below is the holistic code used to capture and transfer the image

```
//Capturing image
               var cameraView = document.querySelector("#cameraView"); //Video element
               var previewCanvas = document.querySelector("#previewCanvas"); // Canvas element

               previewCanvas.width = cameraView.videoWidth;
               previewCanvas.height = cameraView.videoHeight;

               var previewCanvasCtx = previewCanvas.getContext("2d");
               previewCanvasCtx.drawImage(cameraView, 0, 0);

               var dataURL = previewCanvas.toDataURL(imageProps.mimetype, imageProps.quality);

// creating file from dataUrl

        var byteString = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1]);
        var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

        var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
        var _ia = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            _ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);
        var blob = new Blob([dataView.buffer], { type: mimeString });
        var fileObject = new File([blob], fileName + extension, { type: mimetype, lastModified: Date.now() 


//Uploading to server
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append('displayName', displayName);
                    fd.append('fileName', name + imageProps.extension);
                    fd.append('docFileContentType', imageProps.mimetype);
                    fd.append('uploadedFile', fileObject);

                    $http.post(uploadUrl, form, {
                        transformRequest: angular.identity,
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': undefined
                        }
                     })
                   }
```